# Usage of javax.xml.soap in dynamic web applications

Tags: java, soap-client

I have made a code that creates SoapMessage using javax.xml.soap.
When I start this piece of code as java application everything works fine, but when I start it as web application on tomcat I get SoapMessage empty.

1. started as java application

SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
printSOAPMessage(message);

Result: 
SOAP Message =

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body/></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

2. started as web application

SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
printSOAPMessage(message);

Result:
SOAP Message = (*NOTHING*)

```
private void printSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nSOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }
```

Comment: Can you put some configuration code?

Comment: I put some more details